# LockerService Range.commonAncestor readonly field returns a function instead of a Node (or SecureElement)

Tags: aura, locker-service

I've found a strange behavior with LockerService and I do not understand the current behavior.

I want to use [Range.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) but when I try to use this getter, I get a function instead of the closest Node parent.

Fortunately, this is easily reproducible with the Locker Console:

```js
var a = document.createElement('div');
var b = document.createElement('div');
var c = document.createElement('div');

a.appendChild(b);
a.appendChild(c);

var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(b,0);
range.setEnd(c,0);
var rangeAncestor = range.commonAncestorContainer;

alert(rangeAncestor === a);
```

With this snippet I do three things:

1. Create a DOM tree with two element, b and c that have a has common parrent.
2. Create a Range and set its start to b and its end to c.
3. Ensure that the commonAncestorContainer is a

When executed in the [Locker Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console), 'false' pop-up with Locker and 'true' without.

I tried putting a console.log(rangeAncestor) at the end of the code to see if there was a mysterious ancestor: there's not, apart from this strange function.

I found  really hard to believe that is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Salesforce support, this issue ended up fixed.